# JSON (SharePoint) adding a space between the icon and the text

Tags: json, sharepoint

I am formatting my SharePoint columns using JSON. Depending on the text, they display an icon. However, the icon sticks to my text. This is ugly.
How can i add a space between my icon and my text?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, 'OFF:' )>0, 'Red', if(indexOf(@currentField, 'A' )>0, 'Green', if(indexOf(@currentField, 'WEEKLY' )>0, 'Green','Black'))",
    "font-size": "1.20em",
    "width": "400px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, 'OFF: ')>0, 'ReportHacked', if(indexOf(@currentField, 'WEEKLY')>0, 'CalendarWeek', if(indexOf(@currentField, 'A')>0, 'CalendarWeek', if(@currentField == 'B', 'Money', if(@currentField == 'C', 'RecruitmentManagement', 'Alert'))))",
    "padding-right":"40px"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to just change the txtContent to "=@currentField+' '" or "=' '+@currentField"... I think the icon automatically goes to the left but not sure.

You can gain more control over the the text and icon if you separate them into two separate elements though. You could then use padding to separate them, bold one but not the other, make the icon larger without impacting the text, etc. Something like this (fyi-not tested):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, 'OFF:' )>0, 'Red', if(indexOf(@currentField, 'A' )>0, 'Green', if(indexOf(@currentField, 'WEEKLY' )>0, 'Green','Black'))",
    "font-size": "1.20em",
    "width": "400px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, 'OFF: ')>0, 'ReportHacked', if(indexOf(@currentField, 'WEEKLY')>0, 'CalendarWeek', if(indexOf(@currentField, 'A')>0, 'CalendarWeek', if(@currentField == 'B', 'Money', if(@currentField == 'C', 'RecruitmentManagement', 'Alert'))))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
       "style": {
         "padding": "4px"
       }
    }
  ]
}
```